# Is it possible to transform a no-pie executable to pie executable without source code?

Tags: c

I want to transform an executable file to shared library using lief, and I notice that it only supports pie executable. So I wonder if there is a way where no-pie executable can be converted to pie executable.

Comment: Good question and a definite answer has been given ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not, unless perhaps the obscure `-q` option was used when linking. `ET_EXEC` ELF files are linked for a particular load address and have address references resolved and finalized as immediates in in their instruction streams and plain numbers in their data sections. The information that these numbers refer to addresses of objects or functions and aren't just plain constant numbers has **already been lost** and is fundamentally unrecoverable. PIE executables, on the other hand, have dynamic relocation records on all address references so that they can be patched up at load time, and usually have all such references in the data segment (GOT or static data) so that the text segment is purely read-only and shareable.

So no, there's no way to do what you want.

Comment: well, there might be a chance if you've got a very small data / code segment and you can deduce that "hey this number looks like an offset to the data segment". Even then it would be probably just easier to attempt to decompile the executable and recompile it...